# Mysql driver for java

Tags: java, mysql

I tried to install mysql-connector/driver for java using

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-java
```

on my system;

it shows that package not found. What alternative should i try insted of this?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libs/libmysql-java

Comment: Some more info is needed to help with this question. Is your application using jdbc to connect to the database? Are you executing a jar or is this some sort of pre packaged application?  Is there a reason you are trying to install the jar via apt-get instead of downloading it directly?  Usually java apps are packaged with an existing jdbc jar.

Comment: What do you mean "*it shows that package not found*" ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to mysql community download [page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Select the operating system and version of the required connector. Download and install with command specific to your OS for installation.